Kendo Org Chart Select continuously firing
EDIT: I've narrowed down to what I believe is happening. When an alert pops up (or in my actual use case, I post to a form opening a new page), the select event re-fires.
I have a basic Kendo Org Chart. I've run into an issue where the select event continuously fires. Original code was attempting to open another window via a form submit, but I've removed that and gone to basics, the current event is alerting the ID of the selected card.
$("#orgchart").kendoOrgChart({
    editable: false,
    dataSource: dataSource,
    select: onSelect,
});

function onSelect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.dataItems[0].id);
};

When clicked, I get the alert popup with the correct number, then when I close it, the alert instantly pops up again.

A quick example with similar configuration fires the select event only once when selecting/deselecting an item. So I'm not sure what is going on.

@Aleksandar change the select event to be an alert and it absolutely does recreate it in that demo environment.

Seems like the focus is forced to the selected element once again after the alert is closed. Overriding the internal handler seems to do the trick, so most probably this is indeed an issue with the OrgChart:
kendo.orgChart.SingleView.fn._onFocus = function() {
      return false;
    }

